# CSS3 transition breaks in chrome on refresh

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, css-animations

Looked around and haven't found anything similar - finding this really weird.

I have a simple animation on load for a menu at the bottom of a page, sliding the text up a couple seconds after loading (to allow other animations to finish). This works absolutely fine on firefox, IE, android browser and chrome for android. But when I test it on desktop Chrome (44), it doesn't quite work.

What happens is when I load the page for the first time (cleared cache/incognito) the animation will work. But every subsequent time I load the page, it will break - and I have no idea why.

This only happens when I wrap one of the spans in the div inside a link.

The animation is as so:

```
@-webkit-keyframes fadeInBottom {
    0% {
       opacity: 0;
       -webkit-transform: translateY(15vw);
    }
    100% {
       opacity: 1;
       -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    }
}

@-moz-keyframes fadeInBottom {
    0% {
       opacity: 0;
       -moz-transform: translateY(15vw);
    }
    100% {
       opacity: 1;
       -moz-transform: translateY(0);
    }
}

@keyframes fadeInBottom {
    0% {
       opacity: 0;
       transform: translateY(15vw);
    }
    100% {
       opacity: 1;
       transform: translateY(0);
    }
}
```

the css for the spans:

```
.basePanel{
    z-index:999;
    height: 5vw;
    width: 100vw;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    font-size:4vw;
    color:#f1f8f0;
    display:inline-block;
    font-family:coda, courier;
    -webkit-animation-name: fadeInBottom;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1.3s;
    -webkit-animation-delay:1.8s;
    -moz-animation-name: fadeInBottom;
    -moz-animation-fill-mode: both;
    -moz-animation-duration: 1.3s;
    -moz-animation-delay:1.8s;
    animation-name: fadeInBottom;
    animation-fill-mode: both;
    animation-duration: 1.3s;
    animation-delay:1.8s;

}
#contact{
    padding-top: 15vh;
    position:relative;
    font-family:coda, courier;
    text-align:left;
    color:#f1f8f0;
    font-size:6vw;
}
.button{
    position:relative;
    text-align:center;
    width:32.1vw;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 0.3s linear;
    -moz-transition: background-color 0.3s linear;
    -o-transition: background-color 0.3s linear;
    -ms-transition: background-color 0.3s linear;
    transition: background-color 0.3s linear;
}

.button:hover{
    background-color: #252c24;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 0.5s linear;
    -moz-transition: background-color 0.5s linear;
    -o-transition: background-color 0.5s linear;
    -ms-transition: background-color 0.5s linear;
    transition: background-color 0.5s linear;
}

.centre{
    width:32.15vw;
}
```

and relevant html:

```
<div class="basePanel">
    <span class="left basePanel button">About</span>
    <span class="centre basePanel button">Portfolio</span>
    <a href="contact">
        <span class="right basePanel button">Contact</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

Here is a fiddle with the relevant HTML and CSS: https://jsfiddle.net/bqLLqbwc/

Annoyingly, this actually works in Chrome. To see the broken page, here is the actual web page I am working on: http://www.devox.org

I've tested on two computers, one running windows 7 and the other running ubuntu 14.04, both running chrome 44.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ended up restructuring the html a bit.

While it feels like wrapping a `<div>` tag in an `<a>` tag would be easier, it just doesn't seem to work in Chrome. Maybe it breaks some legacy bug from pre HTML5 days. I have no idea.

So instead I wrap an `<a>` tag in a `<span>` tag and change the css to make it fill the div and remove any decoration:

html:

```
<span class="right basePanel button"><a href="contact">Contact</a></span>
```

css:

```
.button a{
    color: #f1f8f0;
    display:block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    text-decoration:none;
}

.button a:visited{color:#f1f8f0;}
```

Which seems to work fine.